# Select top N elements and remember occurence's order

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to select top `N` elements of related products from a big list of products. 
So far, I have below code and it works perfectly.

```
class Product
{
    public string Name;
    public double Rating;
    public List<Product> RelatedProducts;

    public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
    {
        var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
        var relatedListQueue = new Queue<List<Product>>();
        if (RelatedProducts != null && RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
            relatedListQueue.Enqueue(RelatedProducts);
        while (relatedListQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            var relatedList = relatedListQueue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var product in relatedList)
            {
                if (product != this && relatedSet.Add(product) && product.RelatedProducts != null && product.RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
                    relatedListQueue.Enqueue(product.RelatedProducts);
            }
        }
        return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).OrderBy(/*How to order by occurrence here? */).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, I want `GetTopRelatedProducts` method to remember the occurrence order of top `N` products. First added product to the `HashSet` will be at the begining of the returned List.

For example, if I have this scenario:

```
//...
relatedSet.Add(new Product(){Name="A", Rating=3});
relatedSet.Add(new Product(){Name="B", Rating=4});
relatedSet.Add(new Product(){Name="C", Rating=5});
//...
```

and if `N = 2`, the method should return : `B,C` instead of `C,B` because `B` was added first to the `HashSet`.

So I changed the return statement in the method to:

```
        var relatedSetCopy = relatedSet.ToList();
        return (from p in relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rate).Take(N)
                    join c in relatedSetCopy on p.Name equals c.Name
                    let index = relatedSetCopy.IndexOf(c)
                    orderby index
                    select p).ToList();
```

Basically, I use `LINQ Join` to re-order the list in the same way it was before the ordering on `Rating`.

I want to do it this way because first added product has more similarity with selected product than others.

I have two questions here:

1. Is there a better way to re-order the returned list?
2. Is there a better design to handle relation between products? (I was thinking about implementing a tree structure. So object navigation and retrieval will be faster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to re-order the returned list?

You can simply [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.105).aspx) the `relatedSet` with the top N related reordered set because `Intersect` yields the items based on their order in the first sequence.

So instead of

```
return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
```

you would use

```
return relatedSet.Intersect(relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N)).ToList();
```

Comment: There is no simple answer to your second question. If you are persisting such structure in database, probably the way you did it is the only possible way. But if you are building just a memory structure from some source, then probably storing a shared `HashSet` in each product which is part of it (similar to the one we build during the processing, but including also the `this`) could be better.